# Chai's Assert Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, assert, chai

I'm using Chai's assert for checking the values of responses returned from a Server that I've made. However, assert is returning true even when the values passed to it are not equal.
Let me give an example:

```
describe('Tests', function() {
    it('Simple Query', function() {

        // assert.equal(2,3); //returns false

        controller1.simpleQuery(true, 4, "hello", null, function(error, response, context) {

            assert.equal(2,3); //returns true

        });

    });
});
```

Ok so here's the issue: both the assert statements in this code should return false because 2 is not equal to 3. However, right now the assert statement before the simpleQuery()  function call is returning false (which is the correct behavior). And the assert statment within the simpleQuery() call is returning true.

This is honestly really weird and I can't seem to figure out why it's doing this. Can anybody help me figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `simpleQuery` is async. As a result test will complete before callback was even called. You need to show `mocha` your test is async by using `done` callback.

```
describe('Tests', function() {
    it('Simple Query', function(done) {

        // assert.equal(2,3); //returns false

        controller1.simpleQuery(true, 4, "hello", null, function(error, response, context) {

            assert.equal(2,3); //returns true
            done();

        });

    });
});
```

Comment: It fixed the issue. Thanks!